# Lesshat .background-image doesn't work for me

Tags: css, node.js, less, lesshat

i have tried to work with lesshat. I have uploaded lesshat.less mixins libruary to my project root folder. And created 1 .less file - lesshat-tests.less with only one selector and mixin call.

```
@import "lesshat";
div {
    .background-image(linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb83fa 0%,#e93cec 100%));
}
```

I have tried to compile that file with Webstorm less css compiler plugin, and using node.js module less command lessc. Lessc makes empty file, webstorm plugin generate error that tells that plugin can't evaluate JS function.

I saw this mixin using some functions. But i can't get any information about using JS inside less.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mixins of Lesshat are written in Javascript. The less compiler itself is written in JavaScript too and evaluate native JavaScript calls, placed between back quotes, in your Less code.

Probably your Webstorm less css compiler plugin can not evaluate the Javascript calls. The lessc compiler should work.

When i download the Lesshat mixins from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/madebysource/lesshat/master/build/lesshat.less and compile your code by running `lessc yourcode.less` i got the following output in the console:

```
div {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 0%, #e93cec 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 0%, #e93cec 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fb83fa 0%, #e93cec 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fb83fa 0%, #e93cec 100%);
}
```